# Appending to a File with StreamWriter In PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script that writes the results of the permissions of folders in windows to a CSV file using StreamWriter. Currently, the script creates a new file for each folder. My questions is, can StreamWriter append to a file instead of creating or overwriting each time. Thanks,

```
$file_stream_output = New-Object IO.StreamWriter "$path_to_file\results.csv"

$file_stream_output.WriteLine('FolderName,AD Group or User,Permission')

foreach ($directory in $directories_to_search_depth_2[$k]) 
{
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $directory.FullName
    foreach ($access_right in $acl.Access) 
    {
         if ( ($access_right.FileSystemRights -notmatch $exclude_filesystem_rightss_regex) ) 
         {
             $file_stream_output.WriteLine(('{0}, {1}, {2}' -f $directory.FullName, $access_right.IdentityReference, $access_right.FileSystemRights))
         }
    }
}
$file_stream_output.Close()
```

My goal is have results appended to the file.

Comment: Have you looked at the various constructors for the StreamWriter class?  Specifically, have you looked at [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)?

Comment: but this is for .NET, I am talking about PowerShell

Comment: PowerShell is .NET

Comment: okay - so how would I apply this in practice to my code? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Jeff Zeitlin alludes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256798/appending-to-a-file-with-streamwriter-in-powershell/54257188#comment95337878_54256798), the `StreamWriter` class has [a constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) that takes an `append` value as its second parameter - set it to `$true`:

```
$file_stream_output = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$path_to_file\results.csv", $true)
```