# How do I get StreamWriter in PowerShell to create a file and use it?

Tags: powershell

Following the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256798/appending-to-a-file-with-streamwriter-in-powershell) I am trying to write to an output file in PowerShell 7.2:

```
# [String] $csvFile = "output.csv"
[String] $csvFile = ".\output.csv"
$stream = New-Object IO.StreamWriter $csvFile, $true
$stream.WriteLine("Some, text")
$stream.Close()
```

The file is not created. Also, if I create the file beforehand, the script does not write to it. What am I missing? I can get it to work with `Out-File` but the streams are large and I prefer the Net approach.

Is it a permissions issue in the shell?

Comment: `System.IO.StreamWriter` is .Net, so you need to specify an absolute Full path and filename

Comment: .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's, so you should always pass _full, file-system-native_ paths to .NET method calls. Use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) to convert a relative path to a full file-system-native one, assuming it already exists. To specify a file to be created in PowerShell's  current location, use something like `"$PWD\file.txt"`, except from PS-specific drives. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach:

```
# create a new file using the provider cmdlets
$newFile = New-Item -Name output.csv -ItemType File

try {
  # open a writable FileStream
  $fileStream = $newFile.OpenWrite()

  # create stream writer
  $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($fileStream)

  # write to stream
  $streamWriter.WriteLine("Some, text")
}
finally {
  # clean up
  $streamWriter.Dispose()
  $fileStream.Dispose()
}
```

For an existing file, use `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` to find the existing file system item.

The advantage of letting the provider cmdlets deal with the file is that you don't need to worry about qualifying the relative path, `.\output.csv` will be resolves relative to the current location in the shell

Comment: Nice and clean. Trying this now, as `StreamWriter` does not like the DFS URI I am trying to write to... Any chance you can edit this to use `Get-Item` instead. Porting from C# over to PowerShell...

Comment: @Omortis If you provide it as a valid UNC path, eg. `\\domain\dfs-share\folder\file.txt`, then it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it always is for me. Not sure why. I wonder if the `DFSroot$` in the URI is messing things up.

Comment: @Omortis If the share name has `$` in it, make sure that you either escape it with a backtick, or enclose it in a non-expandable string literal. eg. ``$dfsPath = "\\domain\some`$stuff\..."`` or `$dfsPath = '\\domain\some$stuff'`

Comment: As for getting the full, native path of an _existing_ item: The simplest solution is to use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path).

Comment: @mklement0 kaboom! `Convert-Path` fixed the permissions issues, among other things.

Comment: Similarly, if the file is to be created anyway, it is simpler to do `[System.IO.StreamWriter] (New-Item output.csv).FullName` (no need for a file stream).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path when using .Net classes.

Try

```
# get the full path for the output file
$fileOut = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd.ProviderPath, "output.csv"))
$stream  = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($fileOut, $true)  # $true for Append
$stream.WriteLine("Some, text")
$stream.Dispose()
```